# Building a progress bar for Silverlight MediaElement

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, media-player, mediaelement

I want a simple progress bar and a time label that shows the current position of the movie. Google gave me a few examples using Javascript: I really don't want to do that. The key thing is to keep the progress bar and time updated througout the movie. Where can I find that event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no event to hook into.

Instead user a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) to periodically check `MediaElement.Position` for the [MediaElement's current position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.position.aspx) and update your progress bar.

Something like:

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpan currentPosition = Media1.Position;        
    this.Slider1.Value == currentPosition.TotalSeconds
}
```